# how do I add an extra input field to a calendar plugin?

Tags: javascript

How do i get the second input to use the calendar addon aswell as the 1st input?

```
    <head> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type".       content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
    <title>jsDatePick Javascript example</title> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/    css"media="all" href="jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        window.onload = function(){ new JsDatePick({ useMode:2, target:"inputField", dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y" }); };
     </script> 
    </head> 

    <body> 
    <input type="text" size="12" id="inputField" />
    <input type="text" size="12" id="inputField2" />
    </body>
```

Comment: Look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jHgUB/

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything about the plugin, I guess you could just call the `JsDatePick` plugin again, but with another target:

```
window.onload = function() { 
    new JsDatePick({ useMode:2, target:"inputField", dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y" }); 
    new JsDatePick({ useMode:2, target:"inputField2", dateFormat:"%d-%m-%Y" }); 
};
```